# Integration of exponent of basis function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, spline, laplace-method

I have a problem where I need to evaluate $D=\int_a^be^{b(s)^T(c+Au)}ds $ where $b(s)$ is the B-spline. I know the Laplace method but I don't think I can use it here since it's the exponent of B-spline and $(c+Au)$ is not large. Can anyone help me how to evaluate or at least what methods or rules to apply for this kind of equation? The way I can think is

$D=\int_a^be^{b(s)^T(c+Au)}ds $

$=>D=\dfrac{e^{z(s)}}{(c+Au)\dfrac{\partial b(s)}{\partial s}}$

where, $b(t)= {[b_1(t),...,b_p(t)]}$ be a spline basis,

$c$ is a p-dimensional coefficient vector,  $A$ is a lower-traingular p*p matrix

and $u \sim N(0,I_p)$.

Can anyone please at least tell either it's correct or not.

Comment: 1) Please, clearly define the dimensions of $b,c,u,A$ 2) what is a "basis-spline"?

Comment: @lisyarus I have edited the question.